# filter.trim is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-material

This error occurs during filter execution:

```
ERROR TypeError: filter.trim is not a function
```

The filter itself works, just want to somehow get rid of this error.

```
applyFilter() {
  let searchFilter: any = {
    filterValue: this.search,
  };
  this.dataSource.filter = searchFilter;
  this.load()
}
```

html:

```
<div fxFlex="50">
  <mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="search" placeholder="Filter" (keyup.enter)="applyFilter()">
    <button mat-mini-fab matSuffix color="primary" class="btn" (click)="applyFilter()" matTooltip="Filter">
      <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your `filter.trim()` code?

Comment: in what context you are using `dataSource` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Mat table documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api) filter should be a string value and you are passing and object.So you applyFilter should be

```
applyFilter() {
    this.dataSource.filter =this.search ? this.search.trim().toLowerCase() : '';
  }
```

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fggvqq)

Comment: @user12089159 then remove `(keyup.enter)="applyFilter()"` from your input

Comment: @user12089159 i have added the demo please check and let me know if this doesn't work